# How to declare a generic type class that can accept nullable Guid?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following:

```
public class APIResult<T> where T : class?
```

Within this class is a static method called `GenerateAPIResult` which returns an object of type `APIResult<T>`, however `T` may sometimes be null, which is fine for all of my custom classes, but I can't feed in a `Guid?`, because it is a struct. How can I configure this class to handle a `Guid?` return type?

Edit - this is the method:

```
public static async Task<APIResult<T>> GenerateAPIResult(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        ErrorResponseCode errorResponseCode = ResponseCodeHandler.GetErrorResponseCode(content);

        return new APIResult<T>(null, errorResponseCode);
    }

    T returnObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);

    return new APIResult<T>(returnObject);
}
```

and the constructor, for reference:

```
public APIResult(T returnObject, ErrorResponseCode errorResponseCode)
{
    Object = returnObject;
    ErrorResponseCode = errorResponseCode;
}
```

Comment: Why does `APIResult` have the `where T : class?` constraint in the first place?

Comment: Because the `GenerateAPIResult` method (question updated) can sometimes return null and not specifying `where T : class?` throws a compiler error (argument type 'null' is not assignable to parameter type 'T') when trying to do this.

Comment: Maybe use `Guid.Empty` (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) instead of null, and check for that?

Comment: @ataraxia can you please show the code where you are trying to assign `null` ?

Comment: return `default(T)` instead, no constraint necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in a comment that the reason for the `where T : class?` constraint is that the class contains a static method, `GenerateAPIResult`, which can sometimes return `null`, and this results in a compiler error if you don't have that constraint.

It sounds like you can remove the constraint if you have the method return `default(T)` instead of `null`. For classes and nullable types, `default(T)` is `null`; for structs in general, `default(T)` is the value where all fields are default. (I believe that's always the same value as `new T()`.)

Comment: So that means it is simply not possible to return a null Guid then?

Comment: @ataraxia Well, if `T` is `Guid?`, then `default(T)` is `null`. There's no such thing as a null `Guid` since `Guid` is a non-nullable type.

Comment: Got it, I was confusing `default(Guid)` with `default(Guid?)`. Will try this now.